# System.Net.Mail - Unable to email user(s) - getting "Transaction Failed: The Server Response was [domain name here]" error message

Tags: c#, .net, directoryservices, system.net.mail

When trying to submit after selecting a few users or even just one from the checkboxlist in my web form (which is retrieving the emails from LDAP) I (spontaneously) keep getting this error - (it works sometimes and then other times not, and now not completely)

```
"Transaction Failed: The Server Response from was [name of my email host is displayed here - ex: email.domain.com]

[SmtpException: Transaction failed. The server response was: email.domain.com]
   System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint) +1670
   System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint) +226
   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection() +46
   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) +1859
   TestFormV2._Default.SendTesterEmail() in \source\repos\TestFormV2\TestFormV2\Default.aspx.cs:95
   TestFormV2._Default.emailTester_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in \source\repos\TestFormV2\TestFormV2\Default.aspx.cs:110
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +109
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +108
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +31
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3467
```

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace TestFormV2
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LDAPQuery();

        }

        protected void LDAPQuery()
        {
            try
            {
                DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://123.45.678.9:123/cn=TestingCompletion,ou=Groups,dc=domain,dc=domain", "uid=username, ou=people, dc=domain,dc=domain", "password", AuthenticationTypes.None);
                //List<string> GroupMembers = new List<string>(); //{ "first_last", "first_last" };
                StringCollection GroupMembers = new StringCollection();


                Object obj = entry.NativeObject;
                //Console.WriteLine("login success");

                DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);

                search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("uniqueMember");
                search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("uid");
                search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");
                search.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
                search.Filter = "(&(uniqueMember=*))";

                //SearchResultCollection resultCollection = search.FindAll();
                foreach (SearchResult result in search.FindAll())
                {
                    ResultPropertyCollection resultProperty = result.Properties;

                    foreach (string GroupMemberDN in resultProperty["uniqueMember"])
                    {
                        DirectoryEntry directoryMember = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://123.45.678.9/" + GroupMemberDN, "uid=username, ou=people, dc=domain,dc=domain", "password", AuthenticationTypes.None);
                        PropertyCollection DirectoryMemberProperties = directoryMember.Properties;
                        GroupMembers.Add(directoryMember.Properties["mail"][0].ToString());
                    }
                }
                foreach (string member in GroupMembers)
                {
                    //UserDropDownCheckBox.Items.Add(member);
                    UsersEmailList.Items.Add(member);
                    //Console.WriteLine(member);

                }

            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                exceptionMsg.Text = e.Message.ToString();
                //Console.WriteLine(e.Message.ToString());
            }
        }

        protected void SendTesterEmail()
        {

            foreach (ListItem item in UsersEmailList.Items)
            {
                   if (item.Selected == true)
                    {
                    // Send email to selected user(s)
                    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                    mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(item.Value));
                    mail.From = new MailAddress("user_name@email.com");
                    mail.Subject = "Testing Completion Form";
                    mail.Body = "This is a test message";
                    //MailAddress copy = new MailAddress("user_testing@email.com");
                    //mail.CC.Add(copy);
                    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    mail.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
                    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.email.com", 25);
                    //mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(pdfContents, "filename.pdf"));
                    client.EnableSsl = true;
                    client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user_name@email.com", "mypassword");
                    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate (object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };

                    client.Send(mail);

                    SuccessOrFailMsg.Text = "Message Sent Successfully.";

                        //resetFields();

                    }

                }

        }


        protected void emailTester_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SendTesterEmail();

            //clear fields after submit
        }

        protected void resetFields()
        {
            Text1.Text = "";
            systemMenu.ClearSelection();
            otherSystem.Text = "";
            UsersEmailList.ClearSelection();
            dueDate.Text = "";
            SuccessOrFailMsg.Text = "";
        }

        protected void resetFieldsBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            resetFields();
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to send to multiple users from the checkboxlist I have on the form (that is being pulled from LDAP) however its not working! If someone can please guide me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Actually removing SSL and the NetworkCredentials resolved the issue! Apparently our SMTP host does not work with SSL on Port 25.